# Can't understand this basic threads behaviour

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am studying about threads and concurrent programming. Tried this basic example from what was provided in class:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 8

void *printGoGators(void *noArg)
{
  printf("Go Gators!\n");
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc, t;
  for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
    {
      printf("Creating thread %d\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t],
              NULL,
              printGoGators,
              NULL);
      if(rc)
    {
      printf("ERROR %d", rc);
      exit(-1);
    }
    }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

This code produces the following output. :

```
Creating thread 0
Creating thread 1
Go Gators!
Creating thread 2
Go Gators!
Creating thread 3
Go Gators!
Creating thread 4
Go Gators!
Creating thread 5
Go Gators!
Creating thread 6
Go Gators!
Creating thread 7
Go Gators!
Go Gators!
```

Why is `Go Gators!` not printed directly after its corresponding `Creating thread #` for all threads? 
Please help!

Comment: because your threads are independent from each other and from the main thread that creates them. Thus, once initiated, you have no control over which thread is going to print first.

Comment: So this question has been deemed too broad for stackoverflow. I don't see anyone offering different answers.

Comment: It's really hard to make sense of your question. You ask why something doesn't happen without giving any reason why you think it should. You are seeing the behavior you should expect. If you expect otherwise, say why so we can explain the error in your reasoning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code looked like this, then the output would be in the order you expect:

```c++
for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
    {
      printf("Creating thread %d\n", t);
      printGoGators(NULL);
    }
```

So, you're making an assumption that threads will execute in the same order that they are created. However, that assumption is incorrect - threads may execute in any order.

Answer (score 1):

After you create a thread it is up to the OS to decide what order threads are executed. You can control it using mutexes and conditions to lock a thread let another thread to run and then unlock it.

Unlike accepted answer, this example uses threads and not just print something in a loop.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 8

pthread_mutex_t myMutex;                // Declere global mutex
pthread_cond_t myCondition;             // Declere global condition


void *printGoGators(void *arg)    {         

  printf("Go Gators! %i\n", *(int*)arg);
  delete (int*) arg;

   pthread_cond_signal(&myCondition);    // Signal that a condition is met

  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {

  pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, NULL);              // Initialize mutex
  pthread_cond_init (&myCondition, NULL);          // Initialize condition

  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc, t;
  for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)    {

        int* n = new int;
        *n = t;

      printf("Creating thread %d\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t],
              NULL,
              printGoGators,
              n);            

      if(rc)   {
      printf("ERROR %d", rc);
      exit(-1);
    }


  pthread_cond_wait(&myCondition, &myMutex);         // waite for condition

    }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

result:

```
Creating thread 0
Go Gators! 0
Creating thread 1
Go Gators! 1
Creating thread 2
Go Gators! 2
Creating thread 3
Go Gators! 3
Creating thread 4
Go Gators! 4
Creating thread 5
Go Gators! 5
Creating thread 6
Go Gators! 6
Creating thread 7
Go Gators! 7
```

Main thread creation loop: Create a thread and then wait for the condition.

New thread: Print a message then signal that condition is met.

This way you manage the order of execution.